# use the format! macro with something of type Box<dyn Display + 'static>

Tags: string, unit-testing, rust, language-design

I am trying to write unit-tests for a language I am currently writing, so I am working on storing and retrieving variables in the parser except I get the error

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn std::fmt::Display` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> parser/src/env.rs:48:33
    |
48  |         assert_eq!(String::from(format!("{}", *get_binding("test", &env).unwrap().get())), "hello".to_string())
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-
time
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn std::fmt::Display`
note: required by a bound in `ArgumentV1::<'a>::new`
   --> /home/muppi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:314:20
    |
314 |     pub fn new<'b, T>(x: &'b T, f: fn(&T, &mut Formatter<'_>) -> Result) -> ArgumentV1<'b> {
    |                    ^ required by this bound in `ArgumentV1::<'a>::new`
    = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::__export::format_args` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for m
ore info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `parser` due to previous error
```

*my code*

```rust
pub mod env {
    use crate::vars::vars::*;
    use std::{collections::HashMap, fmt::Display};

    #[derive(Default)]
    pub struct Environ {
        pub bindings: HashMap<String, Var<Box<dyn Display + 'static>>>,
    }
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    pub(crate) fn store_var(name: &str, var: Var<Box<dyn Display + 'static>>, env: &mut Environ) {
        env.bindings.insert(String::from(name), var);
    }
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    pub(crate) fn get_binding<'a>(name: &'a str, env: &'a Environ) -> Result<&'a Var<Box<dyn Display>>, String> {
        if env.bindings.contains_key(&name.to_string()) {
            let val = env.bindings.get(&name.to_string());
            Ok(val.unwrap())
        } else {
            Err("Key does not exist".to_string())
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::env::{Environ, store_var, *};
    use crate::vars::vars::*;
    
    #[test]
    fn store_binding() {
        let mut env = Environ::default();
        store_var("test", Var::<i32>::new(Box::new(5), None), &mut env);
        assert_eq!(env.bindings.len(), 1)
    }
    #[test]
    #[should_panic(expected="value not found")]
    fn retrieve_non_existent_binding() {
        let mut env = Environ::default();
        store_var("test", Var::<&str>::new(Box::new("hello"), None), &mut env);
        if get_binding("this_does_exist", &env).is_err() {
            panic!("value not found")
        }
    }
    #[test]
    fn retrieve_binding() {
        let mut env = Environ::default();
        store_var("test", Var::<&str>::new(Box::new("hello"), None), &mut env);
        assert_eq!(String::from(format!("{}", *get_binding("test", &env).unwrap().get())), "hello".to_string())
    }
}
```

The last test is where the error occurs. This test is meant to use the format! macro and format the string to make a string which contains the data stored in the variable.
The var lib

```
pub mod vars {
    use std::fmt;

    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
    pub struct Var<T> {
        pub val: Box<T>,
        pub desc: Option<String>,
    }

    impl<T> std::ops::Deref for Var<T> {
        type Target = Box<T>;
    
        fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
            &self.val
        }
    }
    impl<T> Var<T> {
        pub fn new<Y>(val: Y, desc: Option<&str>) -> Var<Y> {
            if let Some(desc) = desc {
                Var {val: Box::new(val), desc: Some(desc.to_string())}
            } else {
                Var {val: Box::new(val), desc: None}
            }
        }
        pub fn get(self) -> T {
            *self.val
        }
    }
    impl<T> fmt::Display for Var<T>
    where
        T: fmt::Display,
    {
        fn fmt(self: &Var<T>, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
            write!(f, "{}", *self.val)
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::vars::vars::*;

    #[test]
    fn new_var() {
        assert_eq!(
            Var::<i32>::new(10, Some("hello_world")),
            Var {
                val: Box::new(10),
                desc: Some("hello_world".to_string())
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, you can get rid of the `+ 'static`, it's the default for `dyn Trait`.

Comment: You dont need to dereference the Box neither iirc

Comment: we are missing all the `Var` stuff here....

Comment: But how do I print it out?

Comment: Added the var lib

Comment: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c5c6551415c18c3362c11227c00d7662)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the display, it's that you cannot call `get()` on the `&Var` returned by `get_binding()`. For example, this doesn't compile:

```
let x = get_binding("test", &env).unwrap().get();
```

This is because `get_binding()` returns a reference to `Var`, whereas `Var::get()` takes `self` by value (and consumes it). Your attempt to fix the issue by adding a `*` dereference only led you to a new type error which obscured the actual issue and the correct way to address it.

Once the root cause is apparent, the obvious fix is to change `get()` so it takes `&self` and returns a reference, making it compatible with the reference returned by `get_binding()`. For example:

```
pub fn get(&self) -> &T {
    &self.val
}
```

With this change, your test compiles and passes.